# Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am upgrading from cxf 2.2.6 to 3.1.11.

while upgrading I am getting the exception as follows

BaseApplication.main:591 {31/05/2017 05:11:03.117} >> ERROR

> EXCEPTION { 
>     Cause   : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#73c8985f': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.Map]: Factory method 'createTLSServerParametersMap' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory 
>     Message : Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#73c8985f' of type [org.apache.cxf.transports.http_jetty.configuration.TLSServerParametersIdentifiedType] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#73c8985f': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested 
>    exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.Map]: Factory method 'createTLSServerParametersMap' threw 
>    exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory 
>     Class   : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException 
>     Stack   : { 
>       [0] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver(resolveInnerBean:313) 
>       [1] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver(resolveValueIfNecessary:129) 
>       [2] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver(resolveConstructorArguments:634) 
>       [3] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver(autowireConstructor:140) 
>       [4] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory(autowireConstructor:1137) 
>       [5] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory(createBeanInstance:1040) 
>       [6] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory(doCreateBean:504) 
>       [7] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory(createBean:476) 
>       [8] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1(getObject:303) 
>       [9] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry(getSingleton:230) 
>       [10] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory(doGetBean:299) 
>       [11] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory(getBean:194) 
>       [12] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory(preInstantiateSingletons:755) 
>       [13] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext(finishBeanFactoryInitialization:762) 
>       [14] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext(refresh:480) 
>       [15] at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext$1(run:107) 
>       [16] at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext$1(run:105) 
>       [17] at java.security.AccessController(doPrivileged) 
>       [18] at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext(:105) 
>       [19] at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext(:96) 
>       [20] at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext(:78)

for the inputs present in the property file as

```
    <httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">

            <httpj:engine port="0">

                    <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="15" maxThreads="50" />
            </httpj:engine>
    </httpj:engine-factory>
```

Previous it used to work fine with cxf 2.2.6, but after the upgrade I am facing  this issue.

I have both stax2-api-3.1.4.jar and woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar in my classpath, still getting the exception as nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory

Removing this configuration from my property file is not an option for me. As I am eliminating the error when I remove the configuration

So could anyone suggest me a possible solution for it

Thanks in advance 
Rahul

Comment: The previous woodstox jar was present in the classpath at runtime...
wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar(old version of woodstox). 
I removed this jar
Now I am not getting this exception

Comment: could you give me the maven dependency you are using for cxf, I like to run few tests. Thanks in Advance.